# I am getting casting exception while using delete .method of HTTP

Tags: spring-boot, http-method

EXCEPTION ::*"class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Boolean (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Boolean are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"*

@RestController
public class DeleteControllerForStudent {

```
@Autowired
StudentService stdService;


@DeleteMapping("/deleteStudent")
public void deleteByStudentName(@RequestBody Student student)
{
     stdService.deleteStudent(student);

}
```

}

This is my controller . If I am using postman for sending request .. how can I send name

**localhost:8080/deleteStudentByName/{Tushar Joshi}**
This is how I was sending name but I am facing the above exception.
Please reply !!

I tried deleting Student with single name
localhost:8080/deleteStudentByName/{Urvashiii}
I thought I was not sending name correctly .
But I got the same exception again